# Application of Markov chains (processes) for optimizing a random process?

Tags: optimization, markov-chains, markov-process

I am trying to develop a resource allocation model for certain telecommunication application. I have to model my working environment as Markov Process. My question is, Can I perform optimization (or resource allocation w/ optimization) with Markovian models?

Another way around would be to learn optimization theory and I want to skip it if somehow Markov can handle all this.

Comment: Assuming the exogenous state variables follow a Markov chain can simplify many optimization problems. However, you still need optimization theory to solve such problems.

Comment: Thanks. The same is my understanding while I was learning Markov chain. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my latest Understanding(and as commented by @fesman), Markov chain is enough to model the process, but some kind of optimization is necessary. This is my understanding that what kind of optimization methods can be used

1. Linear/non-linear optimization techniques
2. Graph coloring techniques
3. Game theoretic approaches
4. may be some extra!